# how to upgrade my custom android application which will not be released to the Android market?

Tags: android

I tried several links but no one has given any appropriate answer. Scenario is something like :

I have my custom .apk file with version 1.0(let's say) which is already installed in android device(we are not using Android market to install it) and later point of time we have to release the same .apk file with some fixes of application bugs. So is there any possible way to upgrade pre-installed android application without uninstalling it?

Please provide some possible suggestion.

Thanks, piks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be relatively simple:

In the new version of your code, make sure you increment the version numbers like so :

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

Then build your APK and copy it over to your device.

Use something like Astro to open the file, android should detect that you already have it installed, yet this APK will have a later version number so it will give you the option to "upgrade".

Hope this helps.

Comment: and make sure it is signed with same key as the original, just as you would if it were distributed via the Android Market.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.